# show when clicked and then hide when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to bind same functions but different arguments given?

I'm making a dropdown stuff and I'm trying to hide the submenu when parent is click again (refer below)

> when click then show submenu and then when click again and the submenu is displayed already then hide it.o

What I'm currently tried so far (refer below)

jquery

```
$( ".has_sub" ).bind({
    click: function() { //when click and sub is not displayed yet
        $(this).find('.sub').slideDown();
    }, click: function() { //when click and sub is displayed already
        $(this).find('.sub').hide();
    }
});
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li class="has_sub">
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>sub menu 1</li>
            <li>sub menu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.toggle()` rather than `.hide()` you can control the toggle speed `.toggle('fast')` or `.toggle('slow')`

Comment: What about `$(".has_sub").click(function () { $(this).find('.sub').toggle(); });`?

Comment: will be helpful if i solve it using `toggleClass` within `on('click'..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case since you have used the same key twice, the object will have only one property with the value as the value of the last item, so only one handler - the one that hides will get registered.

Since you want to toggle the display with slide animation you can use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```js
$(".has_sub").on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.sub').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has_sub">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: any alternative othen than slide toggle?

Comment: @CodeDemon you can check whether the element is visible if so hide it else show it

Comment: Why use `.bind()` instead of `.on()`?

Comment: i tried :hidden and :visible but sadly none of them works. @j08691

Comment: @CodeDemon why can't you use slideToggle

Comment: @ArunPJohny: thank you, your answer works nice, anyway. how about if I have 2 dropwdown and when I click I click to dropdown 1 then the dropdown sub should be hidden if its been already displayed and same to dropdown 2, when the dropdown 2 is click, the dropdown 1 sub should be hidden if its already displayed. One sub should be displayed per click at a time. how to make that?

Comment: @CodeDemon change the handler to the anchor child... else clicking anywhere in the submenu will close the parent

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for my own blog. Hope, you want similar one:

```
$('#first').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
    $('#second').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Then in CSS you just have to play with `margin-left: -300px;` or with css3 `transform: translate`.

Here is the [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/6H8xr/10/)

Comment: @CodeDemon, you can change `css` as er your requirement! that's the advatange

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".has_sub").on('click', function() {
  var $sub = $(this).find('.sub');
  if ($sub.is(":visible")) {
    $sub.hide();
  } else {
    $sub.slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has_sub">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>sub menu 1</li>
      <li>sub menu 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some great answers here but if you want the menu to stay open until the menu link is clicked again this will do exactly that.

```js
$(".has_sub > a").click(function () { 
    $(this).next('.sub').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.sub{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="has_sub">
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>sub menu 1</li>
            <li>sub menu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li class="has_sub">
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>sub menu 1</li>
            <li>sub menu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Many answers, similar but different methods. Having multiple methods is better than nothing. 
If you have any questions, leave a comment and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!